# How to specify the user with which to create the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have hosting.
Hosting gave me a login and password to the database. I am using these data can go into the database and delete \ create the table.

I am trying to create a database using the data from the code.

```
public class DataContextInitializer:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DataContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Locally everything works, but when I do it on the server I get an error

```
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

How do I fix this? or just my user does not have rights to create \ delete the database?

Comment: have u specified your database name as it is pointing to master?

Comment: no this not master. 'user-4324'

Answer (score 0):

On shared hosting you might not have permission to create a database (you can just modify the database they set you up with). I hit this issue using Code First on AppHarbor when Code First tried to recreate the db = fail.